# Resizing canvas with its text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, createjs

I have one canvas with some text and i want to re-size it in all directions but problem is that text content inside that canvas is getting blurred if i make it re-sizable by using css properties.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

I have tried jquery re-sizable with container to canvas and resize canvas by using css but getting text content's height/width problem and also text is getting blurred.
can anyone help me please..

Comment: See http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas-fullscreen.html for a demo of a resizing canvas that continues to draw content at the original size. If you want to change the size of items as you change the canvas size, then you should `scale()` your context after resizing, before redrawing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, text has many small & tight curves whose flaws quickly become visible if you try to resize the original text.  Therefore, resizing text-especially resizing larger, will always result in the texts natural "jaggies" and anti-aliasing artifacts becoming more visible.

The usual approach to canvas is to treat everything on the canvas as redrawable.  Using that approach, you could clear the canvas and redraw the text using an appropriately resized font.

If your text will always appear topmost on your canvas drawings, an alternative would be to place an SVG element on top of your canvas.  SVG text scales well because it is vector based, rather than pixel based. You could use the svg translate+scale to position & resize the svg text according to your scale factor.  Here's a link showing how it's done: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589508(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes Thanks @markE but canvas text content,font and its size is changing dynamically so getting problems to re draw the canvas.Can you   help me for this ?

Comment: Yes, check out this answers for full details about scaling text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943186/html5-canvas-font-size-based-on-canvas-size